# Android CardBoard VR -navigate from one image to another

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I am developing a cardboard app which shows all rooms of a house, user is allowed to navigate from one room to another by clicking on a button placed in door of next room.

How to place a button on door of next room and how to change to new-room-image while that button is clicked.

It will be helpful if there is any tutorial or code is shared.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the above problem,if so how you are navigation in the VR View as google does not provide any specific implementation for the Google VR SDK for android, the options are only available for Unity and Unreal engine. If you have implemented then it would be helpful if you can share the sample codes.